# Compile error when implementing interface

Tags: ada

I am experimenting a bit (out of academic interest, no tangible use-case) with protected interfaces and have come-up with the following code:

```
procedure Protected_Map is
   type Key is new Character range 'A' .. 'K';
   type Value is range -10 .. 10;
   
   package Maps is
      type Map is protected interface;
      procedure Insert(M: out Map; K: in Key; V: in Value) is abstract;
      procedure Find(M: in out Map; K: in Key; V: out Value) is abstract;
   end Maps;
   use Maps;
   
   -- protected type implementation
   protected type A_Map is new Map with
      overriding
      procedure Insert(K: in Key; V: in Value);
      not overriding
      function Get(K: in Key) return Value;       
   end A_Map;
   
   protected body A_Map is
      procedure Insert(K: in Key; V: in Value) is null; -- dummy
      function Get(K: in Key) return Value is (0); -- dummy
   end A_Map;
   
   overriding
   procedure Find(M: in out A_Map; K: in Key; V: out Value) is
   begin
      V:= M.Get(K);
   end Find;
begin
   null;
end Protected_Map;
```

The idea is to implement a task-safe `Map` by declaring a protected interface type with the associated procedures of inserting and finding values by some key. A protected type is then declared in order to implement the interface which only partly implements it (i.e. `Insert(..)`) and introduces a `Get(..)` function to retrieve a value by some key. The second required procedure (`Find(..)`) is implemented in an independent full-blown way.
The reason for this is so that writers continue to access the map in a mutually exclusive way whilst readers are able to access it concurrently.

However, compilation is failing for `Find(..)` with the compiler complaining that `no selector "Get" for type derived from A_Map`. Why can it not see `Get` which is clearly in the protected type declaration? Is it a scoping issue i.e. do the protected type declaration and the independent implementation need to be in the same package? (or some other unit?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your compiler has a bug with the error message.  The actual error you are making is trying to declare an overriding operation of your A_Map type after specifying a body for the protected type.  Ada wants you to declare all your overrides before the type "freezes" and making a body for the protected type freezes it.  If you add in a declaration for your Find procedure before the body of the protected type, then all is good.  It's a bad error message.

See example

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure jdoodle is
    procedure Protected_Map is
       type Key is new Character range 'A' .. 'K';
       type Value is range -10 .. 10;
       
       package Maps is
          type Map is protected interface;
          procedure Insert(M: out Map; K: in Key; V: in Value) is abstract;
          procedure Find(M: in out Map; K: in Key; V: out Value) is abstract;
       end Maps;
       use Maps;
       
       -- protected type implementation
       protected type A_Map is new Map with
          overriding
          procedure Insert(K: in Key; V: in Value);
          not overriding
          function Get(K: in Key) return Value;       
       end A_Map;
       
       -- Notice the declaration I added here before the body code.
       overriding
       procedure Find(M: in out A_Map; K: in Key; V: out Value);
       
       protected body A_Map is
          procedure Insert(K: in Key; V: in Value) is null; -- dummy
          function Get(K: in Key) return Value is (0); -- dummy
       end A_Map;
       
       procedure Find(M: in out A_Map; K: in Key; V: out Value) is
       begin
          V:= M.Get(K);
       end Find;
    begin
       null;
    end Protected_Map;
begin
    null;
end jdoodle;
```

at https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/K4h

Comment: Interestingly, you can get away (GCC 13.1.0) without `Find`’s spec, so long as you move `Find`’s body before the protected body. Is this right?

Comment: @SimonWright Yeah, as long as that is the only function / procedure.  If you try to do two bodies, the 2nd one may start to error since there is a function/procedure body before it.  I generally just do specs there to avoid that problem if I add another operation later

Comment: Normally it’d never occur to me not to provide a spec - GNAT (`-gnaty`) warns if I don’t. I don’t think it’d’ve occurred to me to use a synchronized interface, let alone OP’s interesting design!

Comment: @jere ah, I see..! So in the "normal" case this is not an issue as all overrides are declared within the protected type _declarations_ so all is good but in a partial implementation this needs to be taken into account. This would explain why the same issue is happening even when the full _body_ of `Find` is placed _before_ the protected type body (i.e. it's the declaration that counts when it comes to where relative to the freezing position it should be placed). Thanks very much all!

Comment: `I don’t think it’d’ve occurred to me to use a synchronized interface, let alone OP’s interesting design!` @SimonWright Yeah, assume you mean a plain protected type/object  would provide the same functionality without so much fuss, don't you? :)

Comment: It’s more that I’ve never felt the need even to use `interface`! The last paid project I worked on was in Ada 95 (I was with it until 2011, but our systems engineers wouldn’t let us change compiler)

Comment: @SimonWright A lot of our software is "reimaginings" of the same baseline, so we only end up changing things like peripherals, but the core logic is the same always.  Interfaces help a lot there on our maintenance, allowing us to just swap out a new component without changing the business logic at all.  We just make sure our core logic uses interfaces and when we swap out peripherals, they all implement those interfaces and fit right in the existing logic.  Super useful for us

Comment: @Sidisyom Yeah, I really do recommend trying to be as expressive as you can in the specs.  It generally leads to a cleaner design, it avoids some of these weird edge case rules, and in some cases the better you specify your code up front the more likely you are to allow the compiler to do some better optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

You code should work, and this looks like a compiler bug to me, probably related to the implicit conversions that happens when using the prefixed view (the "object-dot"-notation), yet should/might not happen when the object in question is a protected object.

The workaround seems to be an explicit view conversion to the protected type:

```
  V:= A_Map(M).Get(K);
```

Comment: Yup, that works too, though the root cause seems to be the one mentioned below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem is that you aren't implementing the interface. In particular, from the interface `Get` is a **procedure**, yet in the implementing type (`A_Map`) `Get` is a **function**; so you are overloading the identifier `Get` but *not* actually implementing the interface.

(Remember, in Ada `Function` is something that returns a value, and that value cannot be silently ignored/discarded, while a `procedure` does not return a value. [Also, WRT unconstrained parameter-types, the `out` is ***not*** equivalent to a function's `return`, because you must accept the constraints that are on the value passed in (such as a String's length) with `out`-mode parameters, but you can return any actual value returning an unconstrained subtype.])

Comment: No: the interface `Maps.Map` has a procedure `Find`, the protected type `A_Map` has a function `Get`. You can call `A_Map.Get` from outside `Find` ... it’s interesting that the compiler’s error message mentions `no selector "Get" for type derived from "A_Map"` ... that "derived from" indicates a certain level of confusion

Comment: Yeah, it looks like _both_ procedures are being implemented, it's just that one (`Insert(..)`) is declared within the protected type whereas the other one (`Find(..)`) is independently declared as a separate subprogram. `Get(..)` is merely an additional subprogram declared within the protected type pretty much in the same way that a non-specification subprogram would be declared in a package body. In addition, implementing `Find(..)` as a null procedure compiles fine.